# Intentando pasar props entre varios componentes: "Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ayer publiqué ayuda para "levantar el estado al componente mas cercano" es decir quería que si se pulsase un botón se pasase un estado a la funcion App que es la ultima que se envía la root del html.

Pues bien estoy intentando imitar lo mismo pero no estoy teniendo éxito. Mi objetivo es que hasta que se pulse un cierto botón, la App sólo carge el componente `<Landing />` (que es como una landing page.)

```js
class App extends React.Component{
  state = {ButtonClicked: false}

  handleSubmit = (ButtonClicked) => {
    this.setState({ ButtonClicked: ButtonClicked })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.ButtonClicked ? <PreApp /> : <Landing handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Una vez que se pulsa (en concreto sería el botón `<a><button>HAZ UN TEST</button></a>`) la App debería cargar el componente `<PreApp />`, que realmente está compuesto de varios componentes:

```js
class PreApp extends React.Component{
  state = { TestIsOn: false }

    handleStateUp = (testInOn) => {
        this.setState({ TestIsOn: testInOn })
    }

  render(){
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NavBar /> 
        {this.state.TestIsOn ? <Test /> : <PreTest />}
        {this.state.TestIsOn ? <FooterTest /> : <Footer handleStateUp={this.handleStateUp} />}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Esto es lo que he puesto en el componente Landing:

```js
class Landing extends React.Component(){
    
   render(){
       return (
        <div>
            <NavBarMain />
            <main>
        <section class="presentation">
          <div class="introduction">
            <div class="intro-text">
             
              <p>
                 lore impsum

              </p>
            </div>
            <div class="cta">
              <a><button class="cta-select">CREAR CUENTA</button></a>
             <a><button onClick={() => this.props.handleSubmit(true)} class="cta-add">HAZ UN TEST</button></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="cover">
            <img src="./images/map-test.jpg" alt="matebook" />
          </div>
        </section>
        </main>
        </div>
       )
   }
}
```

Sin embargo me aparece el error: "TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null"

Como véis el componente Footer en donde la funcionalidad del botón funciona correctamente tiene el mismo esquema el botón (solo que con una funcion con nombre diferente):

```js
class Footer extends React.Component{
   
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <footer>
                    <div class="start-game-container">
                   <React.Fragment><TextInput width={380} height={60} name="text-input-name" placeholder="Escribe un título para este test"/> 
                   <button onClick={() => this.props.handleStateUp(true)} >Crear TEST</button></React.Fragment>
                    </div>
          </footer>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

¿Será por qué estoy haciendo lo de PreApp y App y debería meterlo todo en App? Pero no se hacerlo así porque como hay varios condicionales esto es lo unico que se me ha ocurrido.

Aquí esta el repo online, en cuanto convierto el componente Landing a una clase me da ese error (antes da error una vez que clicko en el botón "CREAR TEST") pero al menos renderiza bien al principio Landing [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://codesandbox.io/s/s)

Comment: Pareciera que te estan faltando los constructores en `App` y en `PreApp`.  `constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {ButtonClicked: false}
  }`

Comment: No era eso pero Acabo de ver el enorme fallo. En la declaración de Landing puse () adicionales en vez de simplemente { }.